# Mongodb findandmodify() Cannot read property 'result' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have problem about nodejs + mongodb findandmodify() function, last week the code below was running ok, but suddenly now it throw error:

```
db.collection(collectionName).findAndModify(query || {}, [], {$set: object},
     {upset: true}, callback || function () {
});
```

if query is undefined that code run ok, but query params ex: "_id": "idofcollection", or "template": "templatename" it throw an exception:

```
E:\Working\Projects\iERP\trunk\client\source\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:309
handleCallback(callback, null, result.result);
                                     ^TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
at E:\Working\Projects\iERP\trunk\client\source\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:309:42
at E:\Working\Projects\iERP\trunk\client\source\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:436:18
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

Please explain for me way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `$or` instead:

```
    db.collection(collectionName).findAndModify({ $or: [ query,  { example: 10 } ] },  {$set: object}, function (){
    });
```

Two things:

1. I am not sure what `callback` was in your code. Usually a callback is [an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677385/node-js-anonymous-functions-and-callbacks).
2. `query` should look something like this `{ price: 5 }`

Here is some documentation of `$or`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but callback is abstract function, and query like you write, and i have changed code for your sugguest but not ok. Addition information: other collections call function findandmodify are ok, is only this collection throw error :(